# Android authentication with retrofit on Json data

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have `Json` data on `firebase` like this;

```
[{"Password":123,"UserName":"User1"},{"Password":34,"UserName":"User2"}]
```

I want to implement authentication depend on this data but problem is that I can only post on Json data for example;

user will enter new data `UserName = User3` and `Password = 44;` my `Json` data will be

```
[{"Password":123,"UserName":"User1"},{"Password":34,"UserName":"User2"},{"Password":44,"UserName":"User3"}]
```

This is not my purpose i want to check the data and return "valid or not" in my originally data.

**Problem is that; i want to check in data availability when i send username and password.If exist return response is "success" if not response is "error".**

My User Class is that;

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("UserName")
public String UserName;

@SerializedName("Password")
public String Password;

public User(String UserName, String Password) {
    this.UserName = UserName;
    this.Password = Password;
 }
}
```

Logon Result class is that;

```
public class LogonResult {
@SerializedName("HasErrors")
public boolean hasError;

@SerializedName("Message")
public String message;

@SerializedName("LoggedUser")
public User loggedUser;
}
```

Retrofit Service like that;

```
public interface CensService {

@POST("/User.json")
Call<LogonResult> login(@Body User userInfo);
}
```

And here is the main method;

```
  final String user = usernameInput.getText().toString().trim();
  final String pass = passwordInput.getText().toString().trim();
  User usr = new User(user,pass);
  final CensClient client = new CensClient();
  final CensService apiService = client.getClient(LoginActivity.this).create(CensService.class);
        Call<LogonResult> userCall = apiService.login(usr);
        Log.w("request",userCall.request().toString());

        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<LogonResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LogonResult> call, Response<LogonResult> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //(response.body().toString());
                }else{
                    //(response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LogonResult> call, Throwable t) {
               //
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is your problem. it occur any error or not.

Comment: and remove .json from this code public interface CensService {

@POST("/User.json")
Call<LogonResult> login(@Body User userInfo);
}

Comment: No error, i just ask how can it authentication.I edit my problem.